# CPU usage is more than GPU usage on Keras, Tensorflow

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I wanted to teach an image classification CNN, and use Keras for it.

The image dimensions are 300x300x3.

I have trained a CNN with 2M parameters, I used MobileNet of Keras for transfer learning, however I freeze last 63 layers and add dense layers at the bottom, the last layer has 2 unit and Softmax activation.

To make predictions, I load the h5 file and use OpenCV video capture to get video frames, for each frame I use model.predict(img_array).

When i look to the Task Manager of Windows 10 , I see that the Python script uses %80 of my processor but %2 of GPU. This CPU usage causes Lags on my laptop.

**How can I reduce the CPU usage and force Keras to make computations with GPU?**

I have Nvidia Rtx 2060 4GB and Intel Core i7-9750H on my laptop.
Tensorflow 2.1 and Keras 2.3.1 
OpenCV 4.1

I have tried, but actually nothing changes.

```
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(12)
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(12)

with tf.device(\gpu:0):
     model.predict(img_array)
```

Best regards.

Edit:

I reduce the CPU usage to %20 with declaring steps parameter in the predict method.

Comment: Your operating system is using cpu by default. You can change it, i know how to do on linux but should be simple also on windows. There should be an interface to do that

Comment: Hi Yunus, thank you for the answer, I have installed Tensorflow-gpu , does not it should use GPU?  If you have a link about the usage of Linux it is also a perfect reference to me. Thanks

Comment: You may need to set backend devece fot dnn, check here : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#gga186f7d9bfacac8b0ff2e26e2eab02625a6d17a7450b1e077ac91faa10a1e85486

Answer (score -1):

Please check your pip list or conda list.

Sometimes, we mistakenly install both ***tensorflow*** and ***tensorflow-gpu***.
If you have both, the system will automatically go for tensorflow, which is the CPU one.

If that is the case, DELETE "tensorflow", keeping only "tensorflow-gpu".

If you do not see tensorflow-gpu in the first place, try installing it on conda using the following commands:

conda create -n [EnvironmentName] python=3.6

conda activate [EnvironmentName]

conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu==1.14

it will assess which version (CUDA,CUDNN, etc.) you require and download and install it directly to your environment. Then run your python file from this environment. Good luck ^_^

Comment: From tf v2 the `tensorflow` binary will have both cpu and gpu support